# C Code Optimization, smooth function

Tags: c, optimization

For an assignment we were asked to optimize the code for a "smooth" function described as:

The smoothing function takes as input a source image src and returns the smoothed result in the destination image dst. Here is part of an implementation:

```
void naive_smooth(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) { 
  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i < dim; i++)
    for(j=0; j < dim; j++)
      dst[RIDX(i,j,dim)] = avg(dim, i, j, src); /* Smooth the (i,j)th pixel */
  return; }
```

The struct pixel stores a red, green, and blue value (integer).
The function avg returns the average of all the pixels around the (i,j)th pixel. Your task is to optimize smooth (and avg) to run as fast as possible. (Note: The function avg is a local function and you can get rid of it altogether to implement smooth in some other way.)
This code (and an implementation of avg) is in the file kernels.c.

Anyone know have some advice for how I can optimize this?

Comment: To start, get an implementation of the algorithm working

Answer (score 4):

You can perform loop tiling/loop strip mining of the loops, by dividing the matrix/image in square tiles and smoothing one tile at a time. This way you achieve better cache utilization.

Consider the current version. It traverses the image, accessing three rows at a time, writing to the middle one.

```
a[i-1][0], a[i-1][1], ..., a[i-1][dim-1]
a[i  ][0], a[i  ][1], ..., a[i  ][dim-1]
a[i+1][0], a[i+1][1], ..., a[i+1][dim-1]
```

By the time it reaches the far right of the image, the first columns will be probably discarded from the cache. But they will be very soon needed, when you move to the next row, where the accesses would be like:

```
a[i  ][0], a[i  ][1], ..., a[i  ][dim-1]
a[i+1][0], a[i+1][1], ..., a[i+1][dim-1]
a[i+2][0], a[i+2][1], ..., a[i+2][dim-1]
```

Instead, you can process the image in tiles, like:

```
a[i  ][B], a[i  ][B+1], ..., a[i  ][B+B-1]
a[i+1][B], a[i+1][B+1], ..., a[i+1][B+B-1]
a[i+2][B], a[i+2][B+1], ..., a[i+2][B+B-1]
```

where B is the tile size.

Or with a picture, to make it more clear:

```
000111222
000111222
000111222
333444555
333444555
333444555
666777888
666777888
666777888
```

Here we have a 9x9 image, split in 9 tiles, numbered from 0 to 8, you goal is to write the loops in such a way that you first smooth all the pixels in tile 0, then all the pixels in tile 1, then all the pixels in tile 2, etc. The order is not important, you can even run each tile in parallel.

Of course, this will be advantageous for large images and for relatively big tiles, you can experiment with the tile size, for example, beginning with a tile row spanning one or two cache lines.

For more info bout this approach, check [Loop tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling)

---

With all that said, it's worth noting that your compiler ought to do this by itself.

Comment: not loop tiling, at least not efficiently in standard compilers nowadays.

Comment: @igon, OK, gcc has options `-floop-block` and `-floop-strip-mine` as well as optimization parameter `--param loop-block-tile-size=N`, although I cannot say how well it works in practice for real-world programs.

Comment: Well yes, but if you look at the man it says: "To use this code transformation, GCC has to be configured with ‘--with-ppl’ and ‘--with-cloog’ to enable the Graphite loop transformation infrastructure." which is an experimental plugin using polyhedral transformations disabled by default as there are no heuristics to determine when it is beneficial.

Comment: @igon, thanks, indeed. I usually enable it in the compilers I build and it never occurred to me that distros leave it disabled by default :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your compiler's optimizations can provide, this would generally benefit from standard optimizations such as *loop unrolling, explicit vectorization, loop blocking,* and possibly *loop interchange* depending on which direction the image is laid out. These should all be covered in your textbook or course notes. If not, those are the keywords to search for online.

Answer (score 1):

Image smoothing is a common example for structured grid applications: [Structured Grids](http://view.eecs.berkeley.edu/wiki/Structured_Grids)

Surely your application will benefit from loop unrolling and loop reordering techniques (especially loop tiling) which you can study here: [Optimizations](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=197406)

Notice that efficiently optimize structured grids computations, especially on a single time step is a not so trivial task and people get PhD's for it: [Stencil probe](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~skamil/projects/stencilprobe/)
Anyway your computations is fairly easy so you should achieve significant speedups.
However, implementing loop tiling can be cumbersome and in some cases counterproductive, you might want to try a polyhedral compiler such as [Pluto](http://pluto-compiler.sourceforge.net/) which is able to quickly produce tiled code with arbitrary tile dimension.
Choosing the correct tile dimension is fundamental in order to achieve good performance and in current architectures, due to the presence of hardware prefetching rectangular tiles work s better: [Cache optimizations](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~oliker/papers/msp_2005.pdf)